# can I put nowadays at the end of the sentence in this case

Tags: meaning-in-context

can I put nowadays  at the end of the sentence in this case?

> Next, the most widely used Android applications are shown, which work based on crowd sourcing, nowadays .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing this adverbial at the end of the sentence makes it difficult to recognize what clause it is intended to modify.

It would be taken in the first instance to modify the subordinate clause it immediately follows:

> Nowadays these applications work based on crowd sourcing (but they used to work based on something else).

If this doesn't make sense (and it doesn't!) it would be taken in the second instance to modify the matrix clause:

> Next, the most widely used applications are shown nowadays (but something else used to be shown).

That again makes no sense. It is only after trying out two other interpretations that we arrive at what you probably mean, with *nowadays* modifying *most widely used*:

> Next, the applications most widely used nowadays are shown.

(Note that an attributive phrase which has a following modifier or complement must be placed **after** the noun it modifies.)

This is what you should have written in the first place, to keep your readers from misunderstanding or just giving up and going to read something else.